# Get Rid of White Dots in Render

Tags: rendering, mesh, eevee-render-engine, light

[image]My rendered image in Blender always shows these small white dots on the edges of the mesh outline. How do I get rid of these? I am using Eevee to render.

Comment: Please include a screenshot of what you are referring to.

Comment: you could try the despeckle node in the compositor

Comment: if you are rendering with cycles you could check the denoise checkbox